# Is it possible to "cleanup" a generator function?

Tags: dart

I'm implementing a library that uses `dart:ffi` to bind functions of `PDFium` in a object oriented manner. Until now, it is quite easy to translate the C functions into dart and hide the whole pointer stuff behind dispose functions and classes.

Now I want to implement the search part and I kind of want to use a generator (sync or async) to create an `Iterable<...>`.

The question is now: is it possible to provide some kind of "cleanup code" for a generator function? If the iterator that is returned never completes, it creates memory leaks. Thus, I need a way to cleanup allocated resources *after* the iterator (or stream) completes.

```dart
class Foo {
  Iterable<dynamic> search() sync* {
    var page = getPagePointer();
    for result in page.search() {
      yield result;
    }
    closePagePointer(page); // <-- how can I guarantee this?
  }
}
```

Maybe there is no way of guaranteeing this, then I will not create a stream/iterator but it would be a nice use-case for a generator function.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet, but "soon".

The problem here is that a `sync*` returns an iterator, and it's very common for people to just throw away an iterator when they've found the element they were looking for, instead of running it to its end.
If they do that, then the `closePagePointer` function will never be called. Using `try/finally` won't make any difference, because the code stalls at the `yield` until someone calls `moveNext`, and they never do. Or maybe they will, some time in the future. You can never know.

What might work is the `Finalizer` class or the `NativeFinalizer` class, both [planned](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47772) for Dart 2.17, if all goes well.

Those will allow you to get a callback when an object is no longer reachable (either best-effort for `Finalizer` or definitely and eagerly, but only with a native callback, for `NativeFinalizer`). If you attach such a finalizer to the iterator of the `Iterable` returned by `search`, you might be able to release the page if the iterator is no longer being used.

Worst case, someone holds on to the iterator forever, but never calls `moveNext` again. That's a case you will never be able to distinguish from someone who might call `moveNext` later.

The slightly more dangerous approach is to time out after some time of not being used, and close the connection.
Something like:

```dart
Iterable<dynamic> search(
    {Duration timeout = const Duration(seconds: 5)}) sync* {
  var page = getPagePointer();
  for (var result in page.search()) {
    bool timedOut = false;
    Timer timer = Timer(timeout, () {
      timedOut = true; 
      closePagePointer(page);
    });
    yield result;
    if (timedOut) throw TimeoutException("Page has timed out", timeout);
    timer.cancel();
  }
  closePagePointer(page); // <-- how can I guarantee this?
}
```

That risks timing out too soon, if someone is being slow (like, waiting for user input before continuing).

Comment: 'Dart 2.17 (the next release)" - What happened with Dart 2.16 (not released yet)? Or are this version being skipped?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. 2.16 is the next release. Internally, it's already in the release pipeline, so new features being worked on *right now* are aimed for 2.17, that's the "next release that new features can yet be added to". Will update original.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm currently testing two workarounds: 1 being iteratively creating the result and return the desired result entirely, and second using a `StreamController` with onListen / onCancel callbacks. as soon as the subscription gets closed, I can cleanup the pointers.

Comment: Streams have better affordances for passing information back from the subscriber. They're also (obviously) asynchronous instead of synchronous, and push instead of pull. If the receiver expects or needs to pull for data instead of getting them pushed when ready, they'll likely pause the stream subscription. If they do that, and forget to start it again, you'll still risk not knowing that they're done. But, for most simple operations, like `.first`, streams will make sure to call `cancel` when they are done, it takes actual effort to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

A [`StreamController`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-async/StreamController-class.html) may help. You get callbacks when the stream is no longer listened to.

A `Stream` is not the same as an `Iterable`, but very useful and versatile.